# regex works in all regex testers, not with php preg_match(), driving me insane

Tags: php, regex

OK, so I have a form that I am trying to extract "20.24" from as below...
When is use regexr.com, works great!

I also need to use "Grand Total" as a reference point, as it's the only constant for the value I am trying to extract

[image: regexr.com testing]

[image: var_dump($text)]

However, when I use that same regex in php 8, it does not work, I have tried numerous variations, and it's driving me nuts.

This outputs nothing...

```
preg_match('/\d+\.\d+\n(?=Grand Total)/i', $text, $out);
var_dump($out);
```

Simon

Comment: Show output of `var_dump($text);` and `var_dump($out);`

Comment: added screenshot of var_dump($text) and var_dump($out)

Comment: Input doesn't have line break but you're matching `\n`

Comment: Why do you use the digits of the previous line with a lookahead as a reference point? Wouldn't it be simpler to just match `/Grand Total: \$(\d+\.\d+)/`?